# What is the perpendicular bisector of $C (3,1)$ and $D (-7,1)$?

Tags: geometry

This is where I am...

$\frac{1-1}{-7-3}=\frac{0}{-10}$

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general advise: always take advantage of the specificities of a problem:

Here, if you draw a figure, you will see that your points, being at the same ordinate have, for their perpendicular bissector, a vertical line intersecting the $x$ axis halfway between $-7$ and $3$, thus with equation $x=-2.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find the mid point of the line given then use **Point Slope Form.**

Comment: Does this work when the perpendicular line doesn't have a slope?

Comment: What do you mean that the line don't have a slope? The line have a slope which is $0$ i.e. $x-\text{axis}$

Comment: The line segment, sure. But it seems as though your advice is to then use the point-slope form to write down the equation of the line perpendicular to it.

Comment: Sorry that my mistake